# How to extract quiz questions from a bank of questions according to its level

Tags: excel-formula

I am creating a test/quiz generator, with no duplicates, from a bank of questions. There are different levels of questions that needs to be extracted accordingly.

I've tried Vlookup and Index/Match. Index/Match seems to be the best method.

worksheet 'CoverSheet' is where I can select the amount of questions to ask and the LEVEL of the question [1 through 10].

worksheet 'QuestionBank' is the bank of questions:

```
ColA                  | ColB           | ColC         | ColD
random# generator     | question level | Question     | Answer
to prevent duplicates |                |              |
```

worksheet 'Test' has two columns Questions:

```
=IF(B1="","",1)
and 
=IF(ROW(A1)>CoverSheet!$D$6, "",
    INDEX(QuestionBank!C:C,MATCH(LARGE(QuestionBank!A:A,ROW(A1)),QuestionBank!A:A, 0)))
```

On the CoverSheet, I want to select # of questions [25] and the level of question [2]. The Test page will select 25 questions ranked as Level 2 from the QuestionBank using ColA random#'s to prevent duplicates. I can't figure out how and/or where to put the extra coding to include the question level (ColB) in the test page.

Comment: Have you considered structuring the question bank so col 1 has level 1 questions, then level 2 questions start in col 10 etc ? Cols 2 to 9 contain details like answers for level 1 questions...

Comment: I've considered it, but the assigned levels are graduated, which means, Level 1 will be general questions that everyone should know, Level 2 will be all of level 1 plus some elevated questions, Level 3 will contain all of 1 and 2, etc. all the way up to 10. So instead of repeating questions for each column, single column of questions seems to be the best way to add and edit questions. Thanks for your input though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a helper column. Consider the following screenhshot.

The question level is numeric. In column C the question level number is added to the random number if the desired level in cell E2 is the same as in column B.

```
=IF(B2=$E$2,B2+A2,0)
```

Now the lookup formula just needs to reference column C for the Match instead of column A.

```
=INDEX(D:D,MATCH(LARGE(C:C,ROW(A1)),C:C, 0))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, Teylyn. This worked perfectly. I would have never thought of adding the level # to the random# and then do a INDEX / MATCH of the result. Thank you again for your skill and knowledge.